# 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm trying to connect the firebase in my app, but I'm getting the same error, I've tried a lot of things, but none of them worked.
First of all, I installed the  firebase and the @angular/fire

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

After that, I changed the environment.ts to

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
};
```

as the documentatio talked. (I put the XX,but in the real environment.ts o put ther correct one). Then, I changed the app.module.ts to

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'guarnice')],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and when I've run the code

```
ionic serve
```

I've got the error.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(17,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'.
>   Property 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.

then I looked for firebase.app.module.d.ts then

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, storage } from 'firebase/app';
export declare type FirebaseOptions = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
export declare type FirebaseAppConfig = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
export declare const FirebaseOptionsToken: InjectionToken<FirebaseOptions>;
export declare const FirebaseNameOrConfigToken: InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig | undefined>;
export declare type FirebaseDatabase = database.Database;
export declare type FirebaseAuth = auth.Auth;
export declare type FirebaseMessaging = messaging.Messaging;
export declare type FirebaseStorage = storage.Storage;
export declare type FirebaseFirestore = firestore.Firestore;
export declare type FirebaseFunctions = functions.Functions;
export declare class FirebaseApp implements app.App {
    name: string;
    options: {};
    auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
    database: (databaseURL?: string) => FirebaseDatabase;
    messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
    storage: (storageBucket?: string) => FirebaseStorage;
    delete: () => Promise<void>;
    firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
    functions: (region?: string) => FirebaseFunctions;
}
export declare function _firebaseAppFactory(options: FirebaseOptions, nameOrConfig?: string | FirebaseAppConfig | null): FirebaseApp;
export declare class AngularFireModule {
    static initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions, nameOrConfig?: string | FirebaseAppConfig): {
        ngModule: typeof AngularFireModule;
        providers: {
            provide: InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig | undefined>;
            useValue: string | FirebaseAppConfig | undefined;
        }[];
    };
}
```

I don't know how I must fix it... I saw I little tips in the stackoverflow and other sites but none of them worked.

that is the documentation I've followed https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.8
Node: 10.15.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.13
Ionic: 4.12.0

 Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.4
@angular/cli                      7.3.8
@angular/fire                     5.1.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.8
@schematics/angular               7.3.8
@schematics/update                0.13.8
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**Update**: This issue has been fixed in [AngularFire2 release 5.1.3](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.1.3). Upgrade to this version to get rid of the problem.

---

Version 5.11.0 Firebase SDK for JavaScript, introduced a change caused AngularFire2 to break. The AngularFire2 team created a fix in release 5.1.3. Alternatively you can stick to `v5.10.1` of the Firebase JavaScript SDK to avoid the conflict.

The issue is tracked on the AngularFire2 repo, so please check here for the latest information: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/2059.

Comment: I did that... in package.json I changed the "firebase": "^5.11.0", to "firebase": "^5.10.1",... after I used npm i, and nothing changed

Comment: I did, I deleted the node_modules and run the npm install

Comment: AngularFire2 version 5.1.3 was just released, which fixes the problem. Please upgrade.

Comment: In fact, I upgraded and I changed the firebase to "firebase": "^5.5.6... and it worked

Comment: Actually... give me the same ... let's help each other